# Emacs: How to set colour of punctuation / C operators?

Tags: regex, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I need a little help with some Emacs syntax highlighting troubles.  I'd like to set the colour of all C/C++ operators.  I am having trouble because "/" is used for division (which I want to colour) but also used to start comments (which I don't want to colour myself, the default code colours them fine.)  I can't seem to figure out how to tell Emacs to only colour a single forward-slash when it is not surrounded by any other forward slashes.

This is what I have now:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil         
    '(("[<>:&*=+^%!~,.?;/-]" 0 font-lock-warning-face t)))
))
```

But it won't correctly highlight something like this:

```
i = 1 / 2
// Test
i=1/2//test
```

Of course if there's already a way of assigning a colour/face to punctuation/operators and I've just missed it please let me know!

Comment: I think the operators need to be separated from each other with a | symbol.  If you do `describe-function` on `font-lock-add-keywords`, you'd see in the example there.

Comment: @vpit: The regexp synatx is OK, the `[` and `]` lists a set of characters to match, in this context the `|` sign has no special meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each font long entry has the following format:

```
(SUBEXP FACENAME [OVERRIDE [LAXMATCH]])
```

The `t` in your rule corresponds to the `OVERRIDE` entry. If you drop it, your rule will not re-highlight something that already has been highlighted, for example comments and strings.

There is no general package for highlighting all operators, but `cwarn-mode` will highlight `=` and `+=` etc. that are embedded inside larger expressions, as well as the `;` in situations where it shouldn't be, like `if (condition);`. It's implemented using functions rather than regexp:s, and I consider it a good reference if you plan to implement relatively advanced font-lock rules.